# Small SVG Distorted in Mobile Safari

Tags: svg, mobile, safari, blurry

I've got some Inkscape generated SVG images that are showing up odd in Mobile Safari. Specifically it seems to be effecting blur on small images. They look fine on desktop (windows), but on mobile safari the smaller the image gets the more extreme the blur becomes until the edges of the blur overflow the bounding box and start clipping, causing a sharp edge instead of the normal gradually fading edge. I've got this simple blurred square (below). On desktop I get a small gray box with blurred edges that gradually fade away. In mobile safari I get a gray box with edges that start fading but the blur is so strong it overflows the filter box and gets clipped.

If I make this same image 500px x 500px, the clipping error goes away.

Naturally this is on much more complex images. All my dropped shadows are a blurry mess. I thought the issue would be obvious once I got it simplified down to a single object, but I'm at a bit of a loss of what else to troubleshoot and I haven't been able to find anything on google.

Anyone have any suggestion on things to try?

```html
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
    
    <svg
       xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
       xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
       xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
       xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
       xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
       width="50px"
       height="50px"
       viewBox="0 0 50 50"
       version="1.1"
       id="svg2900"
       inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
       sodipodi:docname="test.svg">
      <defs
         id="defs2894">
        <filter
           inkscape:collect="always"
           filterRes="50"
           style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB"
           id="filter3479"
           x="-5.867403%"
           width="111.73481%"
           y="-6.1387286%"
           height="112.27746%">
          <feGaussianBlur
             inkscape:collect="always"
             stdDeviation="3"
             id="feGaussianBlur3481" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <sodipodi:namedview
         id="base"
         pagecolor="#ffffff"
         bordercolor="#666666"
         borderopacity="1.0"
         inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
         inkscape:pageshadow="2"
         inkscape:zoom="7.2407734"
         inkscape:cx="55.355565"
         inkscape:cy="10.669427"
         inkscape:document-units="mm"
         inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
         showgrid="false"
         units="px" />
      <metadata
         id="metadata2897">
        <rdf:RDF>
          <cc:Work
             rdf:about="">
            <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
            <dc:type
               rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
            <dc:title></dc:title>
          </cc:Work>
        </rdf:RDF>
      </metadata>
      <g
         inkscape:label="Layer 1"
         inkscape:groupmode="layer"
         id="layer1"
         transform="translate(0,-283.77083)">
        <rect
           style="fill:#808080;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.26458332px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;filter:url(#filter3479)"
           id="rect3445"
           width="148.88914"
           height="197.21333"
           x="42.422787"
           y="74.466438"
           transform="matrix(0.07946474,0,0,0.05948087,-0.40460229,282.00232)" />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

[Safari Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA19I.jpg)

[Desktop Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwlsA.png)

Another example with an inset shadow shows how the blur gets more intense as the image goes smaller. It’s like the blur doesn’t scale proportionally. Both pics are of the same image, both taken in safari. In the first the SVG is displayed in my sites front end at 2px by 10px, in the second I navigated directly to the svg file so it displays at 100% of the browser window.

[small svg in mobile safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrIv9.jpg)

[large svg in mobile safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlMiU.jpg)

Comment: I don't have this sort of problem in Safari but you may try removing the x y width & height of the filter.

Comment: That might fix it for this specific instance but it’s not that the bounding box is too small, it’s that the blur is to intense. So it might fix it for an external shadow but the problem happens with an inset shadow too. So for example I have a square and I add an inset shadow that is offset so the shadow covers about half the width of the box. When I display that very large in Safari I get a nice box that looks like it has depth and a shadow cast halfway across the floor of the interior. When I shrink it down it turns into a blurry mess, with the shadow spanning the whole width of the box.

Comment: This is a square with an inset shadow, displayed on my site, in safari at 2 x 10 px. 

https://i.imgur.com/Kh0FfRT.jpg 

And the same exact svg file but I navigate directly to it so it displayed at 100% x 100% of the browser window 

https://i.imgur.com/4yfMEm2.jpg